# SQL Hunt, Challenging Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a task that I was supposed to do in Informatica. I would just like to be briefed on the possible solutions. I don't specifically need the Queries, just the steps in SQL/Oracle might be of great help.

Problem Statement:

NW Telecommunications is a service provider of cellular communications in India. They have operations in all the states in India. As part of their business operations they collect details about the reasons for service cancellations to improve their customer retention strategies. They are now interested in knowing the major reasons why the customers discontinue their service.

Following are the structure of the source tables

NWT_Connection_Details

```
Phone_No 
SIM (primary key)
Connection_Start_Date
Rate_Plan_Id
Connection_Status
Connection_Closure_Date
Can_Reason_Id
Cust_Id (foreign key)
Home_Location
```

NWT_Cancellation_Reason

```
Can_Reason_Id (primary key)
Can_Text
```

Data in Cancellation reason table:

```
 Can_Reason_Id       Can_Text
 NW              Network Issues
 MNP             Porting to a competitor
 RP              Rate Plan Issue
 RL              Relocation
 CS              Unsatisfactory customer service
```

The result table is a summary table holding the summary of the cancellations happened. The structure of the target table is as follows.

Cancellations_Summary
    Can_Reason
    No. Of Cancellations
    Duration_of_Service
    Zone

Note: Duration_of_Service is a band like < 1 month, 1 to 3 months, 3 to 6 months, 6 to 12 months and > 12 months

**Sample target table data:**

```
NW      18         1 to 3      South
NW      5          1 to 3      South
CS      25         3 to 6      North
```

Comment: this seems like a simple count(*) and group by excercise.  what have you tried?

Comment: Randy: The problem is I am suppose to group by three variables. Zone, dateand  cancellation reason. How can I groupby three variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic query that does what you want:

```
select cr.can_text, count(*)
from nwt_connection_details cd join
     nwt_cancellation_reason cr
     on cd.can_reason_id = cr.can_reason_id
group by cr.can_text
order by count(*) desc
```

I'm answering, though, because this gives an opportunity to comment on certain things.  First, there is no reason why you would even think about doing such a query in Informatica.  This is the type of query that databases are designed for.  Oracle is the best approach.

Second, this probably isn't everything that you want.  You need to take dates into account, customer types, and tenures.  Typically, there is an OLAP system to resolve these sorts of requests (perhaps pivot tables in Excel if the data is not too large).  Such an OLAP system might be loaded using Informatica or using queries from Oracle.

Comment: But implementing it in Informatica would mean that you could have pretty boxes and lines to print out and put on your wall. OK, it would take 1,000,000 times longer to run, but ... um ...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I am so sorry that I cannot vote this up due to my low reputations. Thanks so much